# Access 2010 VBA ptrVar not working

Tags: vba, ms-access, pointers, compiler-errors

I have a problem with my VBA code in Access 2010. I declare a type but when I try to get the pointer of a variable of this type (with the function VarPtr), I get a `compilation error: incompatible type`.

```
Dim dm As DEVMODE
Dim pd As PRINTER_DEFAULTS

pd.pDevMode = VarPtr(dm) ' the line that throws the error

' pDevMOde is a Long that is supose to contain the adress of the dm variable

Private Type DEVMODE
  dmDeviceName As String * CCHDEVICENAME ' (1 To CCHDEVICENAME) As Byte
  dmSpecVersion As Integer
  dmDriverVersion As Integer
  dmSize As Integer
  dmDriverExtra As Integer
  dmFields As Long
  dmOrientation As Integer
  dmPaperSize As Integer
  dmPaperLength As Integer
  dmPaperWidth As Integer
  dmScale As Integer
  dmCopies As Integer
  dmDefaultSource As Integer
  dmPrintQuality As Integer
  dmColor As Integer
  dmDuplex As Integer
  dmYResolution As Integer
  dmTTOption As Integer
  dmCollate As Integer
  dmFormName As String * CCHFORMNAME '(1 To CCHFORMNAME) As Byte
  dmUnusedPadding As Integer
  dmBitsPerPel As Integer
  dmPelsWidth As Long
  dmPelsHeight As Long
  dmDisplayFlags As Long
  dmDisplayFrequency As Long
End Type
```

The problem is that this code was created in a earlier version of Access and works perfectly in versions 2003 and down. I don't know why it does not work in Access 2010. I looked at the differences between 2010 and 2003 versions but I did not find anything related to this.

Does anybody have a clue?

thanks!

Comment: I hope you find my comment :) I am trying out some similar code ... "PRINTER_DEFAULTS" this type where is it defined, which references I need to add to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
there is actually a difference in 64-bit version. The VarPtr no longer returns 
a Long type, it return a LongPtr type variable and my code was not able to put a LongPtr into a Long

refer here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx

> VarPtr |
>   Variant converter. | Returns a LongPtr on 64-bit versions, and a Long on 32-bit versions (4 bytes).

Hope it helps somebody else!